# How to enable audible alarms while making phone calls?

Tags: audio, calls, 4.3-jelly-bean, alarm, clock

I often need to use a timer while making phone calls. No matter what timer I use they never play the alarm sound while you are on the phone, they simply emit a brief "beep" and vibrates (if the timer was configured to vibrate of course).

I need an audible alarm. Is there any way to use a timer with an audible alarm while making a phone call?

It used to be possible, a few Android updates back (can't remember which Android version), but not any more it seems, at least not out of the box.

I've tried the stock Clock app, [Ovo Timer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ilumbo.ovo&hl=en) and [Timer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opoloo.holotimer&hl=en) (by Opoloo). In all three cases alarm signals are only played as expected while not making a phone call.

Comment: The vernacular term you need to be searching for is "in-band ringing".  This is typically a feature of the bluetooth device profile, but I know I've seen in some applications here and there that give you the option of how audio is routed for output that addresses this behavior.  Sorry it isn't much, but I hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but [CircleAlarm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tjeannin.alarm&hl=en) mentions:

> - Handling an alarm that rings during a call.

Comment: Thanks. I need timer though, CircleAlarm seems to be just a regular alarm clock.

Answer (score 0):

With the

> stock Clock app

is this the Google-developed Clock app or a phone manufacturer's Clock app, e.g Samsung? Samsung's Clock app doesn't make an alarm sound during calls, but if you download the Clock app by Google LLC from the Google Play Store, this does play the alarm sound during calls.